# How to create a simple plugin in Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j

I configured Maven and managed to run example-Plugins like FullTextIndex (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-rdf/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/rdf/fulltext/FulltextIndex.java).

Still I struggle to create a simple Function by myself. I want to have a java-function that can find a node by ID and return its properties.

I know I can do this in Cypher, but the target is to understand the logic of plugins for Neo4j.

So after importing the plugin i should be able to type in:

INPUT ID

```
call example.function(217)
```

OUTPUT e. g.

```
name = Tree, age = 85, label = Plant, location = Munich
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Neo4j, user-defined procedures are simple .jar files that you will put in the `$NEO4J_HOME/plugins` directory. Logically, to create a new user-defined procedure you will need to generate this jar file. You can do it [configuring a new maven project](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/#_set_up_a_new_project) or using the repository [Neo4j Procedure Template](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template).

User-defined procedures are simply Java classes with methods annotated with `@Procedure`. If the procedure writes in the database then `mode = WRITE` should be defined (not your case).

Also you will need query the database to get the node by ID and return the properties. To do it you will need inject in your Java class the `GraphDatabaseService` class using the `@Context` annotation.

To achieve your goal, I believe that you will need to use the [getNodeById()](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#getNodeById-long-) method from `GraphDatabaseService` and the [getProperties()](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#getProperties-java.lang.String...-) in the returned [Node](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html).

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `User Defined Functions / Procedures`. There is a dedicated section in the neo4j documentation :

https://neo4j.com/developer/procedures-functions/#_extending_cypher

http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/#user-defined-procedures

You can also look at APOC which contains hundreds of such examples used in real life.

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures